# Python (WSGI web application): Where is an uploaded file stored up until it's read for the first time?

Tags: python, file-upload, mod-wsgi, wsgi

With a Python WSGI web application, here is basic code to get the uploaded file(s) ready to be read using Python's `cgi.FieldStorage`.

```
from cgi import FieldStorage

field_storage = FieldStorage(
    fp=environ['wsgi.input'],
    environ=environ,
    keep_blank_values=True
)

files = {}
for item in field_storage.list:
    if item.filename:
        files[item.name] = field_storage[item.name]            

# Read an uploaded file content
upload_file_content = files['some_uploaded_file'].file.read()
```

Where is this being `.read()` from? Or in other words, where is the uploaded file content
stored when the file is uploaded to the server up until it's `.read()` using `FieldStorage`? Is it in memory, or is it stored in a temporary file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/cgi.html):

> If a field represents an uploaded file, accessing the value via the value attribute or the getvalue() method reads the entire file in memory as bytes.

Comment: I know that it reads into memory, but where is it being read() from? The `files['some_uploaded_file'].file` is a file stream of the uploaded file `<_io.BufferedRandom name=17>` with all the methods like `read(), readline(), seek(), tell()`, but where is this file stream even coming from? Is the uploaded file already temporarily stored in a file on disk, then the FieldStorage creates this file stream from it, then it's read into memory with `.read()`?

Comment: BufferedRandom uses random access memory, so it’s in memory. Since you can call `read`, that means the file is already open. I’m not sure though if the uploaded file is written to disk at some point before the `cgi` package machinery handles the file. If you’re using the `LimitRequestBody` directive in Apache, mod_wsgi might interact with the file in some way, but probably it doesn’t write the data to disk.

Comment: OK thanks. I was just interested in knowing how it worked.